# When is’t vs. isn’t possible to parse-out $x$ from $y$ when each is codependent on the other {bound in expo, tan, etc} to write ‘explicit’ equationz?

Tags: calculus, analysis, problem-solving, analytic-number-theory, recursion

Different types of problems include when the two (or more, but two is complicated as is) variables are each in some operation of the other, such as an exponent, trig.-func., many others, a combination, and recursion (e.g. $x^y=y^x$, $tan(x/y)=sin(y/x)$, $sinx=cosy$, $f(x)=x-f(x(x)$).

Most if not all of these aren’t bijective, but so aren’t many equations without as strong a codependence invertible (such as $x^2-2xy+y^2-8x=-16 ⟺ x=y±2√(2y)+4⟺y=x±√(2x-4)$). What are the cases when an explicit equation definitely is possible, a closed-form less explicit using e.g. product-log function is, certainly neither is, or could be either way depending on finer details?

Comment: I really, really don't think there is a good answer to this question. First and foremost, it is not really a question about mathematics per se, only about what mathematical things we humans have conjured up names for. Which means that a good answer basically needs a full list of those things, as a _starting point_, and go from there.

Comment: @Arthur The implications are relevant. Different types of problems can be solved to different levels of exactness, and recognizing common themes could help narrow-down the methodology and target solution-form.

Comment: Just to handle $x=f(y)$ where $f$ is a polynomial, you'd have to include all of Galois Theory in an answer. The question is way too broad to say much about, without writing a book.